# Incrementing an int during insert

Tags: c#, .net, oledbconnection

I'm trying to increment an integer in an MS Access table from a c# .net page during insert.

I'm getting a syntax error when attempting the following. Also unsure if I should be using an `ExecuteNonQuery()` or not?

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblTarget(target,ref) VALUES(@target,(SELECT MAX(ref)+1 FROM tblTarget)", conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target", TextTitle.Text);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery is fine, but, AFAIK,  there is no way to convince Access to recognize that syntax

Comment: Do any rows exist in the table? So when you do select(MAX) it doesn't return null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to achieve your goal is

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tblTarget (target,ref) " + 
             "SELECT ?, MAX(ref)+1 FROM tblTarget";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target", TextTitle.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 4):

You miss a bracket after `tblTarget`:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = 
    new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblTarget(target,ref) VALUES(@target,(SELECT MAX(ref)+1 FROM tblTarget))", conn);
```

Here is a little review of your code, try using the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) pattern:

```
using(var conn = new Connection())
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO tblTarget(target,ref) VALUES(@target,(SELECT MAX(ref)+1 FROM tblTarget))";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target", TextTitle.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, just spotted that. Now getting System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a bracket, try:

```
INSERT INTO tblTarget(target,ref) VALUES(@target,(SELECT MAX(ref)+1 FROM tblTarget))
```

But I think you are going to have other issues, you need something closer to this:

```
INSERT INTO tblTarget ( target, ref )
SELECT @target AS Targ, First((SELECT MAX(ref)+1 FROM tblTarget)) AS MaxRef
FROM tblTarget
GROUP BY @target;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not do the increment by the sql or code, we can use `AutoNumber` data type for auto increase the value in access.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tblTarget(target) VALUES(@target)";
using(var conn = new Connection())
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target", TextTitle.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You can only have one per table though